# cycle is not a function

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I have the following page http://link.org/ (tested and is valid W3 HTML), where I am using the [jquery cycle slideshow function](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) (old version).

But even though the cycle function file is definitely being called, I am still getting an error: `$(...).cycle is not a function`

Would someone be able to look and see what the issue might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some weird reason jQuery tools are invoking ready event before page is completely loaded, change order of scripts from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
```

and your error will be gone.